# How to mock ResourceGroupCollection using Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, resource-management

My code is the following:

```
SubscriptionResource subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
var resourceGroup = subscription.GetResourceGroups().FirstOrDefault(rg => rg.Data.Name.Equals(resourceGroupName));
```

`GetResourceGroups()` returns an instance of [`ResourceGroupCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.resources.resourcegroupcollection?view=azure-dotnet).  When the `ResourceGroupCollection` is enumerated by `SingleOrDefault`, I'm trying to get the mock to return a mock instance of a `ResourceGroupResource`.  However, I'm not sure how to do that.

So far I have this code in my Moq test:

```
this.resourceGroupCollectionMock = new Mock<ResourceGroupCollection>() { CallBase = true };

Mock<ResourceGroupResource> adfResource = new Mock<ResourceGroupResource>();
ResourceGroupData rgData = ResourceManagerModelFactory.ResourceGroupData(resourceIdentifier, resourceGroupName);
adfResource.Setup(x => x.Data).Returns(rgData);

this.subscriptionResourceMock.Setup(x => x.GetResourceGroups()).Returns(this.resourceGroupCollectionMock.Object);
```

As you can see in my setup, I mocked `GetResourceGroups()` to return the mock `ResourceGroupCollection` object.  But I'm not sure how to add `adfResource` to that mock `resourceGroupCollectionMock`, so that it is returned when the latter is enumerated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: Unfortunately you can't mock `ResourceGroupData` properly because `ResourceData`'s `Name` ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.resources.resourcegroupdata?view=azure-dotnet#properties), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.models.resourcedata.name?view=azure-dotnet#azure-resourcemanager-models-resourcedata-name)) is not defined as `virtual`/`abstract` ;(

```
//Arrange
const string resourceGroupName = "A";

Mock<ResourceGroupData> data = new();
// data
//     .SetupGet(x => x.Name)
//     .Returns(resourceGroupName); 

// The above commented mock setup would throw NotSupportedException

Mock<ResourceGroupResource> resource = new();
resource
    .SetupGet(x => x.Data)
    .Returns(data.Object);

Mock<Response> response = new();
var pagedResource = Page<ResourceGroupResource>.FromValues(new ResourceGroupResource[] { resource.Object }, null, response.Object);
var pagedResources = Pageable<ResourceGroupResource>.FromPages(new Page<ResourceGroupResource>[] { pagedResource });

Mock<ResourceGroupCollection> collection = new();
collection
    .Setup(x => x.GetAll(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int?>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .Returns(pagedResources);

Mock<SubscriptionResource> subscription = new();    
subscription
    .Setup(x => x.GetResourceGroups())
    .Returns(collection.Object);

//Act
var actual = subscription.Object.GetResourceGroups()
    .FirstOrDefault();
    //.FirstOrDefault(rg => rg.Data.Name.Equals(resourceGroupName)); 

// The above commented line would throw NullReferenceException

//Assert
Assert.NotNull(actual);
```

So, if you don't use the `Name` property in your predicate (like in the above sample) then you can mock/fake the rest of the classes.